# If $e_1,\dots,e_n\in R$ are idempotent then $\langle e_1,\dots,e_n\rangle=\langle d\rangle$ for some idempotent $d\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, idempotents

> Let $R$ be a commutatuive ring with a unit and let $e_1,...,e_n\in R$ be idempotent. Prove that $I=\langle e_1,...,e_n\rangle $ and generated by an idempotent element.

**If** $I=\langle d \rangle$ for some $d\in R$ I tries to look at $d=r_1e_1+...+r_ne_n$ and squre it but I didn't really figure it up.

Comment: What does "integral" mean?

Comment: I've corrected it. I thought that "integral ideal" means that the ideal is generated by an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction. For $n=2$, consider $d=e_1+e_2-e_1e_2$ and note that $e_1d=e_1$, $e_2d=e_2$.